# How to represent hex value such as FFFFFFBB in x86 assembly programming?

Tags: assembly, x86, hex, inline-assembly

I'm learning about x86 inline assembly programming.

I wanted to write `mov ecx, FFFFFFBB`, however the compiler isn’t recognizing it. How should hex numbers like that be written in inline assembler code?

Comment: What compiler / assembler?

Comment: another version of this for MASM specifically: [How do I write letter-initiated hexadecimal numbers in masm code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33276232)

Answer (score 22):

It depends on the flavour of your assembler.

- AT&T: `movl $0xFFFFFFBB, %ecx`
- Intel: `mov ecx, 0FFFFFFBBh`

FYI, AT&T syntax is used by assemblers such as the *GNU Assembler*, whereas *NASM* and most of others use Intel's one.

Comment: im using VC++ 10.0 , Digital Mars C++ 10.0 and FASM all using intel-style. 0ffffffbbh

Comment: In fact, GNU as, FASM and NASM do support `0xffffffbb` syntax for hex constants. (GNU as needs `.intel_syntax noprefix` directive to use Intel syntax, or `-masm=intel` passed to GCC).

Comment: @Ruslan I didn't know that feature in GCC! Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

See the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki for links to assembler manuals, and lots of other stuff.

---

Different x86 assemblers support one or both of these syntaxes for hex constants:

- `0xDEADBEEF`: [NASM](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.4.1) (and compat), [GNU `as`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Integers.html), [FASM](http://flatassembler.net/docs.php?article=manual#1.2.4), MSVC inline asm (but *not* MASM), emu8086.
- `0DEADBEEFh`: NASM (and compat), FASM, [MASM](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/books/artofasm/CH08/CH08-1.html#HEADING1-160), TASM, emu8086.

DOS/Windows-only assemblers often only support the `...h` syntax.
Portable assemblers typically support the `0x...` syntax, or both.

**Note the leading `0`:
Numeric constants always have to start with a decimal digit to distinguish them from symbol names.**  ([How do I write letter-initiated hexadecimal numbers in masm code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33276232/how-do-i-write-letter-initiated-hexadecimal-numbers-in-masm-code) is specifically about that, for trailing-h style.)

Also note that assemblers, like C compilers, can evaluate expressions at assemble time, so you can write `foo & 0xF` (if `foo` is an assembler constant, defined with `foo equ 0xABC` or something).  You can even add/subtract from labels (which are link-time constants, not assemble-time), so stuff like `mov eax, OFFSET label - 20` still assembles to a `mov r32, imm32` mov-immediate instruction, just with a different 32-bit immediate.

---

From the [NASM manual's section on constants](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.4.1):

> Some examples (all producing exactly the same code):
>
> ```
>     mov     ax,200          ; decimal 
>     mov     ax,0200         ; still decimal 
>     mov     ax,0200d        ; explicitly decimal 
>     mov     ax,0d200        ; also decimal 
>     mov     ax,0c8h         ; hex 
>     mov     ax,$0c8         ; hex again: the 0 is required 
>     mov     ax,0xc8         ; hex yet again 
>     mov     ax,0hc8         ; still hex 
>     mov     ax,310q         ; octal 
>     mov     ax,310o         ; octal again 
>     mov     ax,0o310        ; octal yet again 
>     mov     ax,0q310        ; octal yet again 
>     mov     ax,11001000b    ; binary 
>     mov     ax,1100_1000b   ; same binary constant 
>     mov     ax,1100_1000y   ; same binary constant once more 
>     mov     ax,0b1100_1000  ; same binary constant yet again 
>     mov     ax,0y1100_1000  ; same binary constant yet again
> ```

---

Most assemblers also allow **character literals**, like `'0'` for ASCII zero.  Or even `'0123'` for four ASCII digits packed into a 32bit integer.  Some support escape sequences (`\n'`), some (like YASM) don't.  NASM only supports escape-sequences inside backquotes, not double quotes.

---

Other platforms:

[ARM assembler](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0473e/Chdhcdai.html): `0xDEADBEEF` works.

I think 0x... is typical.  the 0...h is mostly a DOS thing.

Comment: _MASM_ assemblers by itself doesn't understand 0x prefix even on modern versions of Microsft's assemblers. If you are compiling inline assembly code in VC/VC++ it should accept it within in an `__asm` statement. I don't know an authoritative source, but that has been my experience with _MASM_ /  Visual C/C++ for quite a few years.

Comment: I did confirm that the last version of VC++ that produced 16-bit code (1.52c released in 1993) supported `0x` as a prefix with inline assembly. I took the latest VS 2015's _MASM_ and it failed to assemble an assembly file using `0x` prefix and aborts with `error A2206: missing operator in expression`

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Thanks for checking on that.  Updated my answer to not be biased against the DOS-style `0...h` required syntax, even though I personally don't like it.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your assembler, but a common notation for hex literals is `0FFFFFFBBh`.

Answer (score 1):

Hex numbers are generally always represented with a leading `0x`, so you'd use `0xFFFFFFBB`.

Comment: This wouldn't work for masm, tasm and wasm, for example.

Comment: Hex numbers could also look like: `FFFFFFBBh`, with a trailing `h` instead of a leading `0x`