# How do I write letter-initiated hexadecimal numbers in masm code?

Tags: assembly, hex, masm, masm32

I am currently editing several macros consisting of MASM code.
They all look similar to this:

```
Primary MACRO
Key 0Bh,'0'
Key 29h,15h
Key 03h,'2'
Key 06h,'5'
Key 0Ch,'+'
Key 0Dh,'´'
Key 1Bh,'¨'
Key 2Bh,27h
Key 35h,'-'
Key 34h,'.'
Key 33h,','
Key 56h,'<'
ENDM
```

I have noticed that I can write hexadecimal numbers which are initiated by (begin with) character 0-9 in the following format: `02h`, `12h`, `5Ah`, etc.
However, if I try to write letter-initiated hexadecimal numbers in the same way (that is, like `ABh`, `CAh`, `DFh`, etc.), I get an error. I have tried the format `0xBA`, `0xFE`, etc., but it doesn't work either.

Can anyone tell me the correct format to use for writing letter-initiated hexadecimal numbers in this case?

Comment: Related: [How to represent hex value such as FFFFFFBB in x86 assembly programming?](//stackoverflow.com/q/11733731)

Answer (score 11):

The correct format for hex `AB` is `0ABh`.

The reason you need to start it with a digit is so the assembler can easily distinguish it from a label or symbol such as `ABh`.

And don't worry about the fact it has three digits. It doesn't magically turn into a twelve-bit number because of that, the number of bits used will depend on the addressing modes you're using.