# MSDOS syntax error with DB and undefined symbol while creating boot signature

Tags: assembly, masm, bootloader

In my assembly language project i am facing three errors in corresponding line as given below:

```
1)Message:DB 13,10,"Non- 
 system disk or disk error"
 DB 13,10,"Replace and 
    press any key"
 DB 13,10,0

2)IOSYS: DB "IO    SYS"
   DB "MSDOS SYS"
   DB 0
   DB 0
   ORG 7C00H + 01FEH
   DB 55H
3) DB AAH ;Boot sector 
          ;signature
```

Line1 and line2 error

```
syntax error : DB
```

Line3 error

```
undefined symbol : AAH
```

Please guide me.

Comment: I don't think MASM allows `1)` at the start of a line.  Did you only add that on stack overflow, so that code block is different from the file you actually assembled?  Anyway, I'd guess that a space after the `:` would be a good idea!  The other part is a duplicate of [How do I write letter-initiated hexadecimal numbers in masm code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33276232)

Comment: No, I don't use 1), 2) and 3) in program coding it is only for specification purpose. Actually I used "Message: DB 13,10". And i used space between "Message:" and DB. And same with the "IOSYS:" and DB. But why it is showing error.

Comment: And thanks to you, your guidance solved my 3rd error. thanks Peter.

Comment: I don't know MASM very well.  Some quick googling on that error message found another way it can happen is if the label name is actually a keyword.  So try a different label name.  I'd also be worried about a line-ending inside double quotes.  Normally that's why you'd use something like `db "foo", 13, 10, "bar"`

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove the colon between a label and a `db` statement:

```
IOSYS  DB "IO    SYS"
```

As for the last error: integer constants must begin with a digit, even if they are hexadecimal.  Replace `AAh` with `0AAh` to fix this problem.

Comment: The docs for the [`DB`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/db) directive show that the optional name before the `DB` should not have a colon, although looking at the [BNF Grammar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/masm-bnf-grammar) a _labelDef_ (with a colon) can be followed by a _dataDir_ (with an optional name before the `DB` directive) the `IOSYS: DB` should be legal. There's likely something outside of the BNF grammar to disallow the colon here.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm : There are some semantics involved and has to do with whether the label is defined in a data section or code section. If you place `IOSYS:  DB "IO    SYS"` in a `.data` segment (simplified dos model) it will give you an error. Place it in a `.code` segment and it will be allowed. This has to do with the scoping  of labels within a procedure and those labels that are global.