# Assembly emu8086: wrong parameters: MOV DX,DEF0h

Tags: assembly, x86, emu8086, dosbox

I am learning Assembly language for my studies, and just tested the same program (as shown below) in emu8086 and DOSBox

Below used in emu8086

```
    org 100h
    MOV AX,1234h
    MOV BX,5678h
    MOV CX,9ABCh
    MOV DX,DEF0h
    ADD BX,DX
    ADC AX,CX
    ret
```

Below used in DOSBox Debug mode

```
    MOV AX,1234
    MOV BX,5678
    MOV CX,9ABC
    MOV DX,DEF0
    ADD BX,DX
    ADC AX,CX
```

DOSBox runs fine and produces the result as `AX=ACF1`, `BX=3568`,`CX=9ABC`,`DX=DEF0`.

However, the one in emu8086 doesn't run at `MOV  DX,DEF0h` and gives:

```
(5) wrong parameters: MOV  DX,DEF0h
(5) probably no zero prefix for hex; or no 'h' suffix; or wrong addressing; or undefined var: DEF0h
```

I couldn't identify the error(s) and so here I am to seek for advice. Appreciate any feedback :)

Comment: Like the message says: ‘probably no zero prefix for hex’. Use `0DEF0h`.

Comment: I see, so the hex value should always start with a digit as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33276304/13596315) , but may i know why dosbox supports hex value that begins with letter eventho they both are emulator for x86?

Comment: DOSBox is not an assembler. What are you talking about?

Comment: It appears you're using a DOS Debug application in DOSBox. Debug traditionally defaults to hexadecimal numeric input and does determine that a number is used differently from a full fledged assembler. This is in part related to the fact that it doesn't support symbols.

Comment: yes, I used a DOS debug app in DOSBox, I should've stated it in the post, many thx to both of you