# Arm Assembly: Is cmp r2,0h same as cmp r2,#0?

Tags: assembly, arm, reverse-engineering, offset

I've been reversing some assembly code from a game in an ARM platform, and I've found a **cmp r2,0h** instruction. While looking online for the `cmp` instruction, I've noticed that it actually would compare the value in `r2` with 0 (pseudo-C will be `r2==0`, right?) So I was wondering if 0h has the same meaning? Does 0h equal 0 (unsigned int)?

In general, I find the 'h' after addresses offsets and also after values, so I think it's some kind of flag or something? For example, after the `cmp` instruction there's a **sub  r2,r2,1h**

Thanks a lot.

PS: I'm using no$gba debugger if that matters

Comment: It's certainly not the architectural syntax for a constant, but ultimately disassemblers are free to display things however they want to. I don't recall having ever looked at no$gba specifically, but I'd be incredibly surprised if it meant anything other than a hex value (e.g. 10h == 0x10 == 16).

Comment: @Notlikethat you mean 'h' would mean something like 'hex' right? so 1h would be 1 in hex which is 0x1. Therefore, 0h == 0x0 == 0 right? Seems to be the solution.

Comment: http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/uv4/uv4_db_exp_constants.htm

Comment: when you assembled it and then disassembled it did you see a difference?

Comment: A way to answer this is to look at the binary of the instruction and see if it bit for bit identical to `cmp r2,#0`.  It is in the ARM manuals and you can create binaries constants with many tools (including the assembler with constants and then disassemble the constant).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained by @Notlikethat , the h suffix seems to stand for 'hex' (hexadecimal). Addresses (i.e. 02035000h would be 0x02035000) and values (10h would be 0x10) in no$gba use this suffix.

Comment: DOS/Windows x86 assemblers (like MASM/TASM), [only support the `h` suffix](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37152498/224132) for hex constants, not `0xDEADBEEF` (supported by portable x86 assemblers).  So presumably this choice was made by someone who thought it would be more familiar to asm programmers used to DOS/Windows tools.