# How to represent octal numbers in Assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86

For example for hexadecimal numbers we can use `0x98398` or `8790h`.

How can octal numeric constants be written?  Does this work?

```
mov eax, 70o
```

Answer (score 8):

[NASM supports](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.4.1) `70o`, `70q`,  `0o70`, and `0q70` for octal.

I'd recommend the 0q70 version, to avoid the risk of future (human) readers mistaking the lower-case-o for a zero.  I'm not a fan of the trailing suffix style for hex, either, because it's easy to miss.  It helps to use the opposite case from the rest of the constant, but a leading 0x or 0q is clearer.  (And for hex, avoids the need for a leading 0 to make it a numeric constant instead of a symbol name.)

As for hex-constant support, [it will certainly vary by assembler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11733731/how-to-represent-hex-value-such-as-ffffffbb-in-x86-inline-assembly-programming), so just check your assembler manual.  e.g. most DOS/Windows-only assemblers don't support 0xDEADBEEF, only 0DEADBEEFh style, so I'd guess they have fewer options for octal, too.

See the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki for links to various assembler manuals (and lots of other useful resources and guides).

Comment: Just an observation that if you are using YASM `0q` and `0o` prefix won't work.

Comment: ps: I've found the trailing h notation nice for multiple short 2-digit hex constants; it visually gets out of the way nice, especially if none of them need an extra leading 0 like 0FFh vs. 0xFF.  For octal, you're even more unlikely to just want 2 digits, and octal constants will be rare in most code (e.g. just a file mode) so use something as obvious as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the assembler, but most of the assemblers including NASM allow 0o, o standing for octal. Just like you use 0x where x stands for Hexadecimal.

```
    mov     ax,310q         ; octal 
    mov     ax,310o         ; octal again 
    mov     ax,0o310        ; octal yet again 
    mov     ax,0q310        ; octal yet again
```

Source of information: [Here](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.4.1) .

Again it's not 0o or the syntax above for all assemblers. It might vary by assemblers , but NASM does indeed use the above-mentioned syntax as you can see the link provided for more information. If you have other assemblers in mind, check out their manuel like for FASM: [Here](https://flatassembler.net/docs.php?article=manual) . GAS: [Here](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/gnuasm.html)