# File creation permission issue assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm

I am trying to create a file using some file operations system call in x86_64 Linux assembly code, but I am unable to get the permissions correct. I am tring to set the permission 0777 that is every one can read write and execute but the permissions I am getting on the file are None for owner, group, and others.

What am I missing?

The assembler I am using is nasm.

```
%macro print 2
mov rax,1
mov rdi,0
mov rsi,%1
mov rdx,%2
syscall
%endmacro


section .data
    errmsg db "Incorrect argument count",10
    errmsglen equ $-errmsg

section .bss
    temp resb 8
    sourcefile resb 8

global _start

section .text

_start:
    pop rdx

    cmp rdx, 03h
    jne error

menu:

;------------Extract filename-------------

    pop rdx
    pop rdx

    mov rsi, sourcefile
    mov rax, [rdx]
    mov [rsi], rax

;------------Open File---------

    mov rax,85
    mov rdi,sourcefile
    mov rsi,2
    mov rdx,0777
    syscall

    jmp exit

error:
    print errmsg,errmsglen
    jmp exit

exit:
    mov rax,60
    mov rdi,0
    syscall
```

Comment: Is the file name less than 8 characters? Usually you would either use the arg value directly or use a strcpy to copy it, instead of just copying 8 bytes.

Comment: Yes, I could have used the arg value directly, you are right.

Comment: creat only takes 2 parameters. The mode should be in esi.

Comment: Note also that the mode parameter to creat is modified by umask.

Answer (score 2):

A leading 0 doesn’t indicate octal in nasm. Use 0o777 or 777o.

[How to represent octal numbers in Assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39564402)

Comment: You can also use q instead of o if you find it easier to recognize.

Comment: No, It still has the same issue