# Why doesn't the hexadecimal 'h' suffix work in the GNU Assembler, even when intel_syntax is enabled?

Tags: assembly, intel, gnu-assembler

This fails to compile, despite being valid Intel assembler syntax:

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
mov rax, 10h
```

Whereas this succeeds:

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
mov rax, 16
```

I'm using version 2.26.1 of gas.

Comment: With some assemblers (even Intel ones) it is possibly they don't support the hexadecimal suffix `h`.  With GAS and Intel syntax use `0x` prefix like `0x10` for hex.  `mov rax, 0x10`

Answer (score 2):

`.intel_syntax noprefix` doesn't switch it to NASM syntax.  Directives stay the same, numeric and string constant syntax stays the same.

See [How to represent hex value such as FFFFFFBB in x86 inline assembly programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11733731/how-to-represent-hex-value-such-as-ffffffbb-in-x86-inline-assembly-programming/37152498#37152498) for how different assemblers let you write constants.

The only things that change are:

- the obvious major stuff like operand order, and % and $ decorators
- a few mnemonics, e.g. `movsbl %al, %ecx` becomes `movsx ecx, al`
- how to specify operand-size for memory operands: `DWORD PTR` instead of b/w/l/q suffixes
- bare symbol names are still memory refs (MASM-style).  To get an immediate, use `mov eax, offset symbol_name` instead of `mov $symbol_name, %eax`.

Everything else is still as documented [in the manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/).

GAS `.intel_syntax` (and `objdump -Mintel`) even still has the [AT&T syntax design bug](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dBugs.html#i386_002dBugs) that the `fsubr %st, %st(i)` and `fsub %st, %st(i)` mnemonics are reversed, same for other non-commutative x87 instructions with that pattern of operands.  Thanks, AT&T.

See also the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki for other assembler manuals.  If you really like trailing-h syntax for hex constants, I'd recommend NASM or YASM.  They support both 0DEADBEEFh and 0xDEADBEEF (and similar for binary and octal).