# FASM says error: reserved word used as symbol on base 2 binary constants like 0b101 (C++ style)

Tags: assembly, binary, x86-64, literals, fasm

I need to make a C++ program for an assignment that can add or subtract 1024 and 2048 bit binary numbers, and the functions that do said operations must be made in Assembly. I tried going about this by interpreting the numbers as 64-long arrays of 32 bit binary numbers and adding them one element after another, starting from the end, and writing the result into the third array. However, after making a testing version made for arrays with only 3 32 bit numbers each, I'm faced with the fact that the function doesn't respond. I tried making a version of said function that works predetermined data, but the FASM compiler says "error: reserved word used as symbol.". There isn't an answer I could find anywhere, so now I'm asking for help here.

```
section '.data' data readable writable

IN_NUM1 dd 0b00000100000000000000000000000000, 0b00000100000000000000000000000000, 0b00000111111111111111111111111111     ;"error: reserved word used as symbol" is here
IN_NUM2 dd 0b00000010000000000000000000000000, 0b00000010000000000000000000000000, 0b00000100000000000000000000000000
OUT_NUM dd 0b00000000000000000000000000000000, 0b00000000000000000000000000000000, 0b00000000000000000000000000000000

section '.code' code readable writable executable

start:

        mov edi, [IN_NUM1]
        mov esi, [IN_NUM2]
        mov ecx, 3
        
PUSHING:

        mov eax, [edi]
        push eax
        mov eax, [esi]
        push eax
        inc edi
        inc esi
        loop PUSHING
        
        clc
        
ADDING:

        pop eax
        pop ebx
        adc eax, ebx
        mov [OUT_NUM+ecx-1], eax
        loop ADDING
        
    ccall [printf], [OUT_NUM]
    ccall [getchar]
    stdcall [ExitProcess],0
```

The error message from that line in a file by itself (editor's note: from my computer, not the OP's):

```
flat assembler  version 1.73.24  (16384 kilobytes memory, x64)
foo.asm [1]:
IN_NUM1 dd 0b00000100000000000000000000000000, 0b00000100000000000000000000000000, 0b00000111111111111111111111111111     ;"error: reserved word used as symbol" is here
processed: IN_NUM1 dd 0b00000100000000000000000000000000,0b00000100000000000000000000000000,0b00000111111111111111111111111111
error: reserved word used as symbol.
```

But `IN_NUM1 dd 1,2,4` assembles fine.

Author's edit:
Thanks to the help of @PeterCordes, I have made good progress. However, there are still some issues. With the new code, the addition goes like this: 87654321 + 00000000, FFFFFFFF + 00000001, 04000000 + 02000000. And if I don't multiply ecx by 4, it goes "00000012 + 00000087, 00001234 + 00008765, 00123456 + 00876543". I don't get why this happens, and I would very much appreciate your help. And as for the code itself:

```
section '.data' data readable writable

IN_NUM1 dd 0x12345678, 0x04000000, 0xFFFFFFFF
IN_NUM2 dd 0x87654321, 0x02000000, 0x00000001
OUT_NUM dd 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000

section '.code' code readable writable executable

start:

        mov ecx, 3
        clc
        
ADDING:

        mov eax, [IN_NUM1+ecx*4]
        mov ebx, [IN_NUM2+ecx*4]
        adc eax, ebx
        mov [OUT_NUM+ecx*4], eax
        loop ADDING
```

Comment: Doesn't it also indicate which word that is reserved?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: When a compiler complains about that a reserved keyword is used as a symbol name, the compiler _usually_ indicates what that keyword is somehow.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: I just tried, and that's the unhelpful literal error message.  But clearly it's in the `0b...` numeric literal syntax because changing that lets it assemble.  Many assemblers don't support that C++ syntax, instead using a different letter like `y`, or as suffix such as `101b`.  https://flatassembler.net/docs.php?article=manual#1.2.4  (Also, my FASM said "illegal instruction" when I included the section directive; I guess the default output format for x86-64 Linux is different than the OP's.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to use base 2 in the source code, you can just write them in hex like a normal person.  Any way of writing the same number turns into the same binary bit-pattern in the assembler output.  Also, you could define the arrays and their contents in C++, and pass pointers to your asm functions.

See the FASM manual, section [1.2.4 Numerical expressions](https://flatassembler.net/docs.php?article=manual#1.2.4) (which I found by searching on the word "binary" in the manual):

> The numbers in the expression are by default treated as a decimal, **binary numbers should have the `b` letter attached at the end**, octal number should end with `o` letter, hexadecimal numbers should begin with `0x` characters (like in C language) or with the `$` character (like in Pascal language) or they should end with `h` letter. Also quoted string, when encountered in expression, will be converted into number - the first character will become the least significant byte of number.

So it's [like NASM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37152498/224132) but only supporting **`101b`**,
not NASM's `101y` or `0b101` etc. for base 2.

---

BTW, the first step in dealing with FASM's unhelpful error message was trying a different number syntax, to make sure something like `IN_NUM1 dd 1,2,4` assembled.  Since it did, that shows that the syntax for writing numbers was not what FASM wanted, rather than some other part of the syntax.

---

BTW, you don't need to push and pop your input.  Store your data little-endian (least-significant chunk first) or loop backwards if you really want.  You can increment pointers or an index without affecting FLAGS by using `lea`.  Or `inc` / `dec` leave CF unmodified.  (Older Intel CPUs (P6-family) will have [performance problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32084204/problems-with-adc-sbb-and-inc-dec-in-tight-loops-on-some-cpus) in an `inc` / `adc` loop, but [Skylake has no flag-merging cost at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49867597/what-is-a-partial-flag-stall).)

You could `inc` an negative index up towards zero, and index relative to the ends of the arrays, so your loop logic can be `inc ecx` / `jnz`.  That's pretty good for performance if you're not going to unroll the loop, although `adc reg, [reg + ecx*4]` won't micro-fuse even on Skylake (will [un-laminate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26046634/micro-fusion-and-addressing-modes/31027695#31027695) at issue/rename because of the indexed addressing mode).

Comment: Thank you for your help, by I still have some problems, as stated in the post's edit.

Comment: @SamuelBucher: That's a separate question from the syntax question.  The normal way of using the `loop` instruction will run the loop body with ECX = 3 .. 1, not 0 .. 2.  Your first version used `[OUT_NUM+ecx-1]`; the `-1` is the right idea but you forgot to scale by 4 (the size of a dword).  Or instead of `-4` you could start with `move ecx, 2` and use `dec ecx` / `jge` so the loop body runs for ECX = 2 .. 0