# Assembly prints wrong ascii character

Tags: assembly, binary, ascii, nasm

I was trying to create a simple assembly program that prints the ascii character whose binary code is in rax. I have the following code:

```
section .data
   res db '', 0

global _start
_start:
    mov rbx, 1000001
    mov [res], rbx
    
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, res
    mov rdx, 1
    syscall


    mov rax, 60
    xor rdi, rdi
    syscall
```

When I execute, it outputs 'A', which is correct since 1000001 is the binary code for ascii A, but if I execute this:

```
section .data
   res db '', 0

global _start
_start:
    mov rbx, 1000010
    mov [res], rbx
    
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, res
    mov rdx, 1
    syscall


    mov rax, 60
    xor rdi, rdi
    syscall
```

It outputs 'J', but according to the table I used 1000010 should output 'B'. What makes this even stranger for me is that if I use decimal instead of binary I get the right output. What am I doing wong?

Comment: Almost a duplicate: [How to represent hex value such as FFFFFFBB in x86 assembly programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37152498) includes the `mov     ax,1100_1000b` and other syntax that NASM allows for binary (base-2) numeric constants.  Of course you should just `mov ebx, 'B'` if that's what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1000001<sub>10</sub> = F4241<sub>16</sub>, and 41<sub>16</sub> = 65<sub>10</sub> = A <sub>ASCII</sub>

1000010<sub>10</sub> = F424A<sub>16</sub>, and 4A<sub>16</sub> = 74<sub>10</sub> = J <sub>ASCII</sub>