# error: invalid operand type when mutiplying by register

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, addressing-mode

I am making a program in x86_64 assembly language and it requires me to offset a memory address by a variable. I am trying to use the `*` to multiply the address by `edx` however, I get the following error:

```
    kernel.asm:23: error: invalid operand type
```

Why is this happening and how do I fix my problem? Here is my code:

```
mov edx, 1
mov ebx, 0xb8000+160*edx
inc edx
```

Comment: Read the instruction set reference on what addressing modes are supported.  The one you are trying to use is not.

Comment: You can't perform arbitrary arithmetic at runtime in a single instruction; you have to do it step by step, one instruction at a time.  That's what "instruction" means.  You can do arithmetic with *constants* because the assembler will do the computation and just encode the result, but `edx` isn't a constant.

Comment: There are certain *specific* combinations of arithmetic operations that can be done in effective address computations, and the assembler uses an algebraic-style syntax for those.  This sometimes misleads people into thinking they can use *arbitrary* algebraic expressions, but it's not true.

Comment: I recommend getting your cross compiler working. See https://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler . If you have a cross compile question ask over on the OSDev community forum here https://forum.osdev.org/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thing is that your instruction is invalid, because memory operands are required to be in wrapped in square brackets. Applying this change you would have `mov ebx, [0xb8000+160*edx]`. Using the [Intel/MASM/DOS notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11735095/1305969) for hexadecimal numbers as NASM also allows, you'd get `mov ebx, [0b8000h+160*edx]`. This instruction would still be wrong, because the SIB byte of the instruction encoding on x86 ISA only allows scale factors of `2`,`4` and `8` as described in Table 2-3 of the *Intel Manual*. 160 is not a valid scale factor. Finally, you want to calculate the address, so better use `LEA` and not mov: `lea ebx, [0b8000h+2/4/8*edx]`.

You have to calculate the value with other instructions like `MUL`, `IMUL`, `SHL` or `INC` to get the resulting value you want.

For example, you can do the following calculation to position your cursor (with ECX=X and EDX=Y) assuming an 80x25 text mode (using [`IMUL`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/imul) instead of `MUL` as suggested in the comments):

```
mov ecx, X             ; where X might be [esp+8] or [xpos] or whatever
mov edx, Y             ; you may not need a register, imul-immediate can load
; with inputs in registers
imul ebx, edx, 160    ; calculate line offset
lea ebx, [0B8000h + ebx+ecx*2]  ; add column offset and base address
                      ; Now EBX is Y*160+X*2
```

Comment: Even if the multiplicator was fine for SIB encoding, they'd have to use `lea` not `mov` to make use of it.

Comment: Well, the instruction `MOV` would be valid, but probably not as useful as `LEA` in this context.

Comment: If you had the right factor **and** added the square brackets, to make that a memory access, yeah. But to calculate the address and not dereference it you'd need those two changes and `lea`

Comment: Yes. Sorry I wasn't clear enough. I thought of an instruction like `mov eax, dword ptr [0B800h+edx*4]` or something like that.

Comment: Why would you use `mul` here instead of `imul edx, eax, 160`?  The code in the question doesn't show any sign of wanting the full 64-bit result of 32x32 multiplication.  Also, the question is using NASM syntax, so square brackets are *always* required for memory operands.  But AFAIK, all assemblers require square brackets when a register is involved, so your answer should really say something about `0xb8000+160*edx` being total nonsense, not just an invalid scale factor.