# Trail "h" in HEX notation

Tags: hex

What's the difference between 0x040h and 0x04?

How this difference should be understood? And where/when each should be used?

I've already seen this [Rules for when to append -h/-H to hex numbers in assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823240/rules-for-when-to-append-h-h-to-hex-numbers-in-assembly).

Comment: There is no difference. You know how some people like to be called "mate" and some prefer "buddy"? Yup, same here.

Comment: You're asking about the difference between two ways of *writing* something. The answer is going to depend on what language or other system you're interacting with. There won't be one catch-all answer.

Answer (score 0):

> What's the difference between 0x040h and 0x04

The latter is an acceptable way to write 4 in a C program, the former is not. The 'h' is also redundant with '0x' prefix, which *already* implies hexadecimal in many (most?) programming languages.